# Docker PHP:FPM 7.2 can't set session.save_handler, it always default to "files"

Tags: php, docker, fpm

I'm currently trying to update the `"session.save_handler = files"` and `"session.save_path = null"` to my own values but they always default to files.

In my case I have setup the php redis extensions and I would like to setup to `"session.save_handler = redis"` and  `"session.save_path = https://rediserver:6375"`, however, after updating the config files either updating directly on **/usr/local/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf** or adding an extra .conf file to /usr/local/etc/php-fpm.d/session.conf and restarting php-fpm with "kill -USR2 1" the values are not updated when I check using `php-info()`; function.

Any idea what might be happing ? I'm using docker image php:7.2-fpm .

Thanks

Comment: Look at this suggestions https://github.com/phpredis/phpredis/issues/1097#issuecomment-275914047. Try to modify pool.d conf file instead of php-fpm.d/*.conf

Comment: thanks for the reply @Panoptik . But I can't find the pool.d configuration file, doesn't seem its running as it. I did found in the URL you sent to try with php_admin_value parameter but that didnt work either. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue, I was using supervisorD to load my php-fpm therefore the command kill -USR2 1 wasn't making any effect to reload the php changes. The solution was to kill manually my php-fpm process and make supervisord start again with '"supervisorctl restart [task name]"'